# Symfony 5 Form class Entity Manager

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form in FormType class and I pass Entity manager throught constructor.

Here is example of code: Controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType($em));
```

here is my controller code :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Form\FormulaireType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class FormulaireController extends AbstractController
{
    public function nouvelleAction(Request $request): Response
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        if (4 != $session->get('niveau')) {
            throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
        }

        $em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $form = $this->createForm(FormulaireType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager instance
            $sm = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()->getSchemaManager();
            $em->getConnection()->exec('CREATE TABLE custom_'.$form->get('liste')->getData().'(lead_id int(9) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (lead_id)) ENGINE = MYISAM');

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'La formulaire de la liste avec identifiant '.$form->get('liste')->getData().' a été bien crée');
        }

        return $this->render('formulaire/nouvelle_formulaire.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
    }
}
```

here is my FormType class code :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\VicidialCampaigns;
use App\Entity\VicidialLists;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormulaireType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('campagne', EntityType::class, ['label' => 'les campagnes', 'class' => VicidialCampaigns::class,
                'choice_label'                            => 'campaignName', 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'], ])
            ->add('liste', ChoiceType::class, ['label' => 'les listes', 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']]);

        $fc = function (FormInterface $form, $campagne): void {
            $listes    = $this->em->getRepository(VicidialLists::class)->findBycampaignId($campagne);
            $leslistes = [];
            if ($listes) {
                foreach ($listes as $liste) {
                    $leslistes[$liste->getListId()] = $liste->getListName();
                }
            }

            $form->add('liste', ChoiceType::class, ['label' => 'les listes', 'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control'],
                'choices'                                   => $leslistes, ]);
        };
        $builder->get('campagne')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($fc): void {
            $fc($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData());
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            // Configure your form options here
        ]);
    }
}
```

Symfony 5 has change in method createForm to:

```
$this->createForm(SubjectType::class);
```

And with this declaration, I don't know how to pass entity manager to form class.

Any help ?

Comment: Form types are services by default so just inject whatever you want into the constructor. https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_custom_field_type.html#passing-variables-to-the-form-type-template

Comment: in my case how can i edit my code ?

Comment: You should not have to do anything different except use $this->createForm(FormulaireType::class);  The Symfony form factory is container aware so when it comes to instantiating the type class it first checks the container to see if a service with the same id is defined.  If so the service is used which means your entity manager will be injected.  That's assuming you have autowiring setup etc.  I can't guarantee the rest of your code will work but the manager should be injected just fine.